# Freemarker XML parsing with attributes and value

Tags: xml, parsing, freemarker

I have the following XML that contains two attributes and a value. The value containing the content is wrapped in a field tag.

```
<field key="title" primitive="String">
<![CDATA[
This is the problem that I'm trying to solve.
]]>
</field>
```

After I parse it, I get this when I type ${item} in the freemarker template. I can get the attributes using item.@key and item.@primitive. Unfortunately, I'm failing get the value or the content. My alternative solution is to use substring to get the content from the value array. I'm sure freemarker has a way to get this sort of data.

```
field[attributes={key=title, primitive=String}; value=[This is the problem that I'm trying to solve.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `item` holds the `field` XML element, `${item}` should work. The output you show isn't familiar to me. So I guess there's something strange with the XML wrapping there, like perhaps you are using some of the legacy XML wrappers. You should use a W3C DOM `Element` or `Document` added to the data model, or wrapped explicitly with `freemarker.ext.dom.NodeModel`.

BTW, you can try on http://freemarker-online.kenshoo.com/ that it indeed should work, if you fill the form like this:

Template:

```
<#assign item=doc.field>
${item}
```

Data model:

```
doc=
<field key="title" primitive="String">
<![CDATA[
This is the problem that I'm trying to solve.
]]>
</field>
```